# call function after sails lifted

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, cron, sails.js

I am trying to call function that use firebase services after sails server start I have tried these ways in bootstrap.js file but it didn't work ,I think config folder run before sails server start
I have search on it document but didn't found much help

The function I am trying to call have a cron jobs and this function exists on services folder

```
  sails.after("lift", function () {
       cronJob()
  });

 sails.on("lifted", function () {
    cronJob()
      });
```

I have put on my app.js

```
require('firebase-admin').initializeApp()
```

but every time I try to run another function using firebase services too it show me that error and when I comment cronJob() function error gone

```
{
    "code": "app/no-app",
    "message": "The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services."
}
```